# how to spoof outgoing UDP socket port number in linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

The question is the title.
But I'd like to describe my problem so that someone can suggest an alternative solution.
I know that when the client sends a message on a socket to 12.34.56.78:40, the router on the client's side sets a rule for some time that any data received from the 12.34.56.78:40 is allowed and will be sent to the client machine on the network.
so the problem I have is that the client is sending to the server on some port but the server needs to reply using a different socket (thus a different port). but ofcourse the server's ip didnt change.
so that was my first idea of solving the problem
spoof the outgoing port

Comment: Learn about *raw sockets*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket

Comment: *Why* does the server 'need to reply using a different socket'? A UDP server only needs one socket.

Comment: @EJP well, I have a lot of classes that are sending/receiving. I thought it would be a bad design to keep passing on the same socket all over the functions.

Comment: Well you were mistaken about  that. All  you accomplished was to create this extra, imaginary, problem. And waste resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple sockets can bind to the same port, and thus send packets with the same source port number, if the each socket sets the SO_REUSEPORT socket option. See [the SO_REUSEPORT socket option](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/) and [the difference between SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t).